# SQL command to turn 261/261/261/261/262/262 into 261/262

Tags: sql, hana

What kind of SQL operation has be applied to get from point A to point B :

point A

261/261/261/261/262/262/261/262/261/261/261

point B

261/262

Thanks

I can't use DISTINCT , GROUPING prior to STRING_AGG operator , I don't see any other option how to reduce the number of 261, 262

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here. Could you clarify what point A and point B represent in your example? Are point A and B single string values, i.e., you have a single row containing the text value "261/261/261/261/262/262/261/262/261/261/261" and want to return "261/262"? Or are there 11 rows you're trying to reduce to 2 rows, and you're delimiting the rows with /?

Comment: single row containing the text values  into single row containing compressed text values

Comment: Maybe look into what regular expression (regex) functionality is available to you from the database you're working with. If you can find a function which would take your string and use a regex to return the 11 matched numbers as rows. You could then do a distinct on this and string agg them as you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily achieve this by using [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/02/10/split-string-into-multiple-rows-using-sql-in-sap-hana/#:%7E:text=Use%20SPLIT_TO_TABLE%20function.&text=As%20input%20for%20SPLIT_TO_TABLE%20function,variable%20defined%20in%20point%20II.) hana function. Once you get the split values as rows in a one column table you can `SELECT DISTINCT` them and then `STRING_AGG` them as documented [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_SERVICE_CF/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/a924ee1e98ab435a874efa32e6f0ae14.html)

I'll let you put together the code to do this as I don't have a hana running environment to verify the correctness.

Hope it helped.